# Oracle SQL: Function with a cursor using no data found return value

Tags: sql, oracle, function, cursor

I am trying to write a function to extract a code from a string, look up a value in a table based on that code and return the value from the lookup table.

This is my function:

```
   create or replace function MATHS_F 
   (id IN varchar2)

   RETURN number
   is res_code VARCHAR2(2);
   points number(3,0);     

   cursor c1 is
   select substr(substr(lcstring, instr(lcstring,'02')+2),1,2) 
   from sdata s
   where s.id = id;

BEGIN

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into res_code;

   select c_points into points from lcresults l 
   where l.lc_code = res_code;

RETURN points;

close c1;

exception when no_data_found then
   return 99;

END;
```

I am running this statement to test my function:

```
select id, lcstring,
substr(substr(lcstring, instr(lcstring,'02')+2),1,2) RESULT,
MATHS_F(id) as POINTS
from sdata
where id = 'S00101620'
;
```

The result of this query is

```
S00101620    11OT02OV29HV05OT03OX30OQ  OV   99
```

There is a value of 35 in C_POINTS in LCRESULTS table for LC_CODE 'OV'...
Why is my function finding no data?

Comment: It's probably because function parameter has same name as column in `sdata`. Try to change parameter name or change `where s.id = id;` to `where s.id = maths_f.id;`

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! That was the problem. I have just spent all morning looking at this! Hopefully some day I will be able to contribute to this forum!

Comment: @Anne-Marie . . . Instead, rename the parameters.  In fact, I always preface variables in Oracle with something like `v_`, to minimize the possibility of this happening.

Comment: What's the reason behind deciding a function is the way forwards for this? You would be better off replacing this function with an outer join to the lcresults table. It will perform much better, for a start!

Comment: @Boneist I opted for a function as I am trying to build up a materialised view to use in a data mining application. I'm fairly new to SQL and I want to be sure that each attribute in the data mining source has accurate data. I thought that by creating a function to decode the string it would be easier than adding another table to the view joins... (BTW the 99 value for no data found will be replaced with a null value once I'm happy with the function so that any genuine null values can be replaced with MEAN during the data pre-processing phase)

Comment: in general, if you can do something in SQL, you should do so; it will (except in very rare cases) perform better. Using a user-defined-function here makes no sense to me. As well as doing a left join to the lcresults table, you could also rewrite this as a query without left joining (to take advantage of scalar subquery caching) - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d9e49/1/0

Comment: Thanks so much Boneist... that is really useful. AM

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor c1 is
  select substr(substr(lcstring, instr(lcstring,'02')+2),1,2) 
  from sdata s
  where s.id = id;
```

the final line of this query is NOT using your input parameter.
Try to change parameter name or change `where s.id = id;` to `where s.id = maths_f.id;`

also on another point you are not correctly closing your cursor as your `CLOSE` statement is after the return.. nor does it close if a `NO_DATA_FOUND` is raised

try

```
create or replace function MATHS_F 
   (p_id IN varchar2)

   RETURN number
   is res_code VARCHAR2(2);
   points number(3,0);     

   cursor c1 is
   select substr(substr(lcstring, instr(lcstring,'02')+2),1,2) 
   from sdata s
   where s.id = p_id;

BEGIN

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into res_code;
   close c1;

   select c_points
   into points 
   from lcresults l 
   where l.lc_code = res_code;

   RETURN points;


exception when no_data_found then
   return 99;

END MATHS_F;
```